# Retrieve user email for username signing firebase

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am making a sign in with username in Firebase. I want to retrieve user email and sign in with email, while the user types username and password.

In other words, get an email from the database which corresponds entered a username.

```
let username = usernameTextField.text
Database.database().reference().child("members/email")
```

I cannot go further from this point

Comment: 1. this is very basics of dat querying. please research. 2. you should add more details, most important - what is in the database? structure & data of members/email  is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the username for login? Use email password auth provided by firebase. see this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth

What you are trying to do needs to expose all the username and emails from database to every one which is not a secure solution. Using firebase authentication you have to trade off username for email as username